# Prevent jUnit from failing if assumption not satisfied

Tags: junit

When running a series of test cases using jUnit, it is possible to skip the test for some cases using assumptions. However, if there are no cases in which the assumption is satisfied, the test is marked as failed. Is there a way to prevent that?

For example, if the property testTopic is passed as vertical_move, all of the tests for vertical_move should run and none of the tests for horizontal_move. Currently I am using assume as shown below to skip these tests.

```
assumeTrue(TestCons.get("testTopic").contains("horizontal_move"));
```

The problem is that if the assumption fails in all cases, the test is marked as failed. I want it prevent that. In other words, if the assumption fails, just skip the test without failing it, even if the assumption is never satisfied. Is there a way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @Ignore to mark tests that should be completely excluded from execution, but I am not aware how you could determine that from *within* a test case.

And honestly: I think you shouldn't even try that.

Unit tests should be straight forward. They exist to help you to quickly identify a bug in your production code. But: any piece of "extra logic" that a reader needs to digest to understand the reason for a failing testcase makes that harder.

Thus: avoid putting any such extra logic in your test cases. Write testcases that create a *clear* setup, and then assert for the result that you expect for exactly that setup, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You are right about @Ignore not being a good idea. However, the thing is this is for a continues test suit. Therefore, it has to adopt to different conditions. I'm looking into overriding fail, if I could come up with a way to achieve my goal with that I'l post it as a response.

Comment: Reminding me is all is needed my friend. Thus, upvote you shall have... (bows in humbleness). P.S. I like your username!